# stop words removal using c#

Tags: c#, text, stop-words, removeall

I have two string arrays i.e.

```
string[] text = {"Paragraph 1 containing long text of ten to 20 lines", "Paragraph 2 containing long text of ten to 20 lines", "Paragraph 3 containing long text of ten to 20 lines",.....};
```

and another array of stop words i.e.

```
string[] stop_words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\stopWords.txt");
```

`string[] text` array is containing paragraphs of text and `string[] stop_words` array consists stop words to be removed from all the texts stored in
`string[] text` array

How the stop words can be removed using c#. Code suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a homework exercise to me... so I'll guide you in the right direction. Look at `for` and `while` loops (I'm assuming you won't have got to LINQ yet) and the `Replace` method of the `String` class.

Comment: The issue is how to match each stop word in stop_words array with every single text of text array

Comment: You could have a `for`-loop going through the strings in `text`, and then an inner `for`-loop that is replacing all stop-words in the current string in `text`.

Comment: I have checked nested loop, it works but if a string "i" is replaced then it leaves a white space there for which if we have to remove next word i.e. "am" but in original text that is returned after removing "i" is " am" so it can't match "am" in stopword_list to " am" in text

Comment: Can you follow my answer flow, now tell me how does it not apply to your case?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
string[] result = text.Except(stop_words).ToArray();
```

or else you can try using for loop

```
string[] stop_word = new string[] { "please", "try", "something" };

string str = "Please try something by yourself before asking";
foreach (string word in stop_word )
{
   str = str.Replace(word, "");
}
```

Comment: text and stop_words are both arrays of strings........so can't be processed as mentioned here

Comment: a single string i.e. "Please try something by yourself before asking" can be processed by this method but I have array of strings containing itself long text paragraphs at each array index

Comment: @user3495173:- You got an idea...now put some effort and try that yourself. Trust me thats not so hard to do.

Comment: what problem does long text paragraph create, each one is again a string, may be a big string

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the flow:

1) I have to iterate over the input_Texts string array..fine.

2) Inside the loop I split the paragraph on the basis of space i.e (' ') so that I get all the words in it.

3) Then I find all the Intersecting/matching words between them and the stopWords.

4) And then take all the words except the matching words.

5) Join them with space again to create back the text from words(devoid of stopWords) and put it into the same place back again.

```
  for(int i=0;i<input_Texts.Length;i++)
  {
    input_Texts[i]=string.Join(" ", input_Texts[i].Split(' ').Except(input_Texts[i].Split(' ').Intersect(stopWords)));
  }
```

Can you follow this?